How to combine two jupiter swaps in one?
I'm new to solana and I'm trying to combine two swap transactions I got from jupiter API. In my attempt I got multiple types of errors depending on how the transaction's structure. I will post an error logs example but sometimes its different
logs: [
'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]',
'Program log: CreateIdempotent',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
'Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1569 of 1394295 compute units',
'Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
'Program log: Initialize the associated token account',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
'Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner',
'Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 1387708 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3158 of 1383826 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 19315 of 1399700 compute units',
'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 invoke [1]',
'Program log: Instruction: SharedAccountsRoute',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
'Program log: Instruction: TransferChecked',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 6200 of 1363832 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: swap_program. Error Code: ConstraintRaw. Error Number: 2003. Error Message: A raw constraint was violated.',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 consumed 30615 of 1380385 compute units',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 failed: custom program error: 0x7d3'
]
var serializedTransaction = await decodeBase64Transaction(transactionData1.swapTransaction);
            const serializedTransaction2 = await decodeBase64Transaction(transactionData2.swapTransaction);
            

            const instractions1 = serializedTransaction.message.compiledInstructions
            const instractions2 = serializedTransaction2.message.compiledInstructions
            // console.log(instractions1)
            // console.log(instractions2)
            var table1 = serializedTransaction.message.addressTableLookups
            var table2 = serializedTransaction2.message.addressTableLookups

            table1.push(...table2)
            // console.log(table1)
            // console.log(table2)

            var addressLookupTableAccounts = await Promise.all(
                table1.map(async (lookup) => {
                    // console.log(typeof(lookup.accountKey));
            
                    let publicKey;
                    
                    if (lookup.accountKey instanceof PublicKey) {
                        publicKey = lookup.accountKey;
                    } else if (typeof lookup.accountKey === 'string') {
                        publicKey = new PublicKey(lookup.accountKey);
                    } else {
                        throw new Error("Invalid accountKey format");
                    }
            
                    const accountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(publicKey);
                    if (!accountInfo) {
                        throw new Error('Account info not found');
                    }
            
                    return new AddressLookupTableAccount({
                        key: publicKey,
                        state: AddressLookupTableAccount.deserialize(await connection.getAccountInfo(publicKey).then((res) => res.data)),
                    });
                })
            );
            
            
            var message = TransactionMessage.decompile(serializedTransaction.message,{addressLookupTableAccounts: addressLookupTableAccounts})
            var message2 = TransactionMessage.decompile(serializedTransaction2.message,{addressLookupTableAccounts: addressLookupTableAccounts})
            message.instructions.push(...message2.instructions.slice(2))
            console.log(addressLookupTableAccounts.length)
            console.log(serializedTransaction.message.addressTableLookups.length)
            message.recentBlockhash = serializedTransaction2.message.recentBlockhash
            console.log(message.instructions)

            serializedTransaction.message = message.compileToV0Message(addressLookupTableAccounts)
            
            
            serializedTransaction.sign([wallet]);
            const rawTransaction = serializedTransaction.serialize()
            

            
            const { txid } = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction,{preflightCommitment: 'confirmed'});
            await connection.confirmTransaction(txid);
            console.log(`Transaction ID: ${txid}`);```


You can try Jito Labs Bundles.
